# Some Troubles in A Little C Program

Tags: c

I don't really write codes but nowadays I wanted to make a secret folder which is going to stay in my desktop. I've made the batch files that makes the secret folder appear and disappear. I want to make a c program which is going to execute the batch files by entering password. But I have some issues in my code. I'm not really into this job and I need a simple description which is going to solve troubles in my code.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {    

    char *choose;
    char *password = 'efe';
    char *entered_password;

    printf("enter the password:\n");
    scanf("%s", &entered_password);   

    if(entered_password == password) {
        printf("access accepted!!!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("access denied!!!\n");    
    }

    printf("What you want to do?\n\tOpen the Gate:open\n\tClose the gate:close\n");    

    int a = 1;
    char open[5] = "open";
    char close[6] = "close";

    do {
        scanf("%s", choose);

        if(strcmp(open, choose) == 0) { 
            printf("Starting\n");

            ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\cl_op\\open.bat",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

            a--;
            return 0;
        }
        else if(strcmp(close, choose) == 0) {
            printf("Bye\n");

            ShellExecute(NULL,"open","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\cl_op\\close.bat",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWNORMAL);

            a--;
        }   
        else {
            printf("Try again\n");
        }
    } while(a > 0);   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Batch file or C? And can you indent your code, properly, so that it is readable.

Comment: regarding: `char *password = 'efe';`  This is a multi character problem  Suggest: `char *password = "efe";`

Comment: regarding: ` scanf("%s", &entered_password);`  in C, referencing an array name degrades to the address of the first element in the array  So, no need for the `&`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", choose);`  this has a few problems 1) code failed to check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifier `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input field.  OH BTW  there is no input field, just some pointer (chose) pointing to some random location in memory.  A good way to cause a seg fault event.   Strongly suggest learning about the C library, rather than wasting time with the microsoft extension (which you will not see anywhere else (cont)

Comment: suggest learning about the `system()` function call` Or perhaps better, the `exec*()` family of functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the comparison code for `entered_password` you are comparing the strings with `==`. You should use `strcmp`
2. `entered_password` and `choose` should be declared as a char array of suitable length.
3. In the case where the password is not matched, you should exit the program with `exit(1)` or `return 0`
4. `%s` requires the address of the array. you can directly give the base address as the parameter
5. You should use `"efe"` while initializing a the char pointer `password`

   ```
   char choose[30];
   char *password = "efe";
   char entered_password[30];

   printf("enter the password:\n");
   scanf("%s", entered_password);   

   if(strcmp(entered_password,password)==0){
       printf("access accepted!!!\n");
   }
   else{
       printf("access denied!!!\n");  
       exit (1);        
   }
   ```

Comment: Happens, I would also mention that placing the password in the exe is a security risk. Generally hashes of the password are what gets stored and after the user enters the password, the password is hashed and compared to the password-hash. That way the password is not disclosed with a simple call to `strings yourpwprog`.

Comment: I am not sure that having a C program like this will actually secure the files. As OP has mentioned in another comment, this is a small program just for fun. Most probably the batch file is just hiding the files or copying from a undisclosed location to the desktop.

Comment: Yep, I understand, but without mentioning the risk, (even though you need not provide an example), the OP may continue with a misunderstanding that hardcoding a password in an exe somehow makes it secure.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem that I spotted in that you have not allocated any memory for the inputted password. Next your first `if` compares two pointers, not two strings.

I recommend a different language:

`python3` will be good for this, or `go` (if you need to compile to native code).

Other problems:

- I can get your password by running `strings «program name»`.
- I can circumvent the the security by directly running the external programs (batch files). I can find the external programs by running `strings «program name»`.

Comment: That is not for real security. I just want to protect my secret things from my mates and family.

Comment: As long as your mates are MS-Windows users, then it may work, but it would take me less than 30 seconds.